BC547 transistor rectifier circuit with diodes 1N4007 and capacitor

I CANNOT DO THIS ON BREADBORD CAN YOU PLEASE HELP OR PROTEUS IMAGE IS ACCEPTABLE :)
Circuit Explanation
Power Supply (VDD):

A 15V DC power supply is used to power the circuit.

Input Signal (Vin):

A 1 kHz sinusoidal wave is applied as the input signal at the base of the NPN transistor (Q1). This signal represents the AC input for the circuit.

Transistor (Q1 - BC547):
Type: BC547, an NPN bipolar junction transistor (BJT).
Connections:
Collector (C): Connected to the VDD (15V) via a 10kΩ resistor (R1).
Base (B):Receives the input sinusoidal signal.
Emitter (E): Connected to ground through a 2kΩ resistor (R3).
Resistors:

R1 (10kΩ): Limits the current to the collector of the transistor.
R3 (2kΩ): Provides a ground reference for the emitter of the transistor.
R2 (2kΩ): Connected to the output node and helps with current flow in the circuit.
Capacitors (C1 and C2):
C1 (100µF): Connected between the collector and the first diode (D1), it acts as a coupling capacitor to block DC components while allowing the AC signal to pass.
C2 (100µF): Connected between the emitter and the output node to stabilize and smoothen the output signal.

Diodes (D1 and D2 - 1N4007):
D1: The anode is connected to the collector (via C1), and the cathode is connected to the output node.
D2: The anode is connected to ground, and the cathode is connected to the output node after R2.

These diodes appear to perform rectification of the AC signal to produce a DC-like output.

Output Signal:
The output is taken from the junction of D1, D2, and R2.
This output signal will be a rectified version of the input sinusoidal signal due to the diodes.

Circuit Operation Summary
The circuit takes a 1 kHz sinusoidal input signal*and processes it through the BC547 NPN transistor.
The transistor amplifies the signal, and the diodes (1N4007) act as rectifiers to convert the AC signal into a DC-like signal.
Capacitors C1 and C2 help block DC components and stabilize the output signal.

Unclear what you are asking.  What is preventing you from doing this on a breadboard?  It seems straightforward.  Did you try it and it's not working?  Show a picture of what you tried and the waveforms.

Is this homework? If so, to help you we need to know what you have tried and where you are stuck.

i need help because i cannot be able to do this kind of sine wave involving circuits on breadbord and i dont know how to show it on proteus @JohnD

@ChesterGillon it is my laboratory experiment and i am not good at breadbords. so i cannot do that

So, not good at breadboards (why?) and don't know how to use Proteus. Not much to go on. May I suggest you try a Proteus tutorial.

You can never have a capacitor directly in series with a diode without some other component such as a resistor to pass the DC component. A diode only passes DC, a capacitor only passes AC - nothing with get through!

Some parameters are missing. Vbe (mean) and amplitude Vin ?

@GodJihyo - you are wrong. Assuming that the capacitors are initially discharged any current flowing through the diodes will charge up the capacitors until they reach the peak voltage of the AC; from that point no current will flow because the diodes will be reverse biased even at the peak of the AC signal.

@KevinWhite Ah, my bad. I probably shouldn’t look at this stuff when I’m lying in a hospital full of painkillers :D

@GodJihyo - no problem. Best wishes for your recovery.

Without giving away too much, there are two serious problems with the circuit.  For example, why is R1 shown as 10K?

Fun Fact: I traced this phase-splitter circuit back to a pair of 1942 patents, which are improvements of a 1938 patent.

This circuit lack a "polarization" DC voltage.
With a DC applied with generator, here is what simulation says ...

The voltage output "vo" is a "quasi" double alternance rectifier.
Note that resistor R1 need not to be 10 kOhm.
Note also that your "text" description is not "clear" and is "not equivalent" to your "figure".

Please don't make other people's homework. Also your diagram and the OP's diagram are not drawn according to the text how the diagram should be drawn, so the simulation result and waveforms are not correct either.

Ok. Not the "same figure" OP as text "displays".
