Trying to replicate a full-wave rectifier circuit in ngspice, but I'm running into an issue where the output isn't behaving as expected
I am in 12th grade, and I have just started learning ngspice. I was experimenting with a part of a circuit that works as a full-wave rectifier, which I found online. I was trying to apply it and analyze its behavior over time (the image of the circuit is shown below with the corresponding nodes).

However, my graph does not rectify the wave, and there is no voltage at node 5. At first, I thought it could be due to the capacitance of the capacitors or perhaps the wave's voltage being too weak. Yet, even after changing those parameters, the voltage at node 5 still remains at zero, like this:

I considered it might be a polarity issue, but when I change the polarity, although I do get a voltage, it turns out to be negative. For example:

If someone could point out what I am doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it. Here is the script:
Circuit with 7 nodes for rectification

AC Voltage Source
V2 7 0 SIN(0 5 1k) ; Sinusoidal signal with amplitude 5V and frequency 1kHz

DC Voltage Source
V1 1 0 DC 15 ; DC voltage source with 15V

Resistors R1 R2 R3
R1 1 2 10k ; Resistor R1 between Node 1 and Node 2
R2 3 0 2k ; Resistor R2 between Node 3 and Ground
R3 5 0 2k ; Resistor R3 as load connected between Node 5 and ground

Diodes
D1 6 5 DIODE_1N5819 ; Upper diode: Node 6 -> Node 5 (anode -> cathode)
D2 4 5 DIODE_1N5819 ; Lower diode: Node 4 -> Node 5 (anode -> cathode)

Capacitors
C1 2 6 200u ; Upper capacitor
C2 3 4 200u ; Lower capacitor

Transistor
Q1 2 3 7 NPN_BC547 ; NPN transistor with base at Node 2, emitter at Node 3, and collector at Node 7

Component Models
.MODEL NPN_BC547 NPN(IS=1E-14 BF=200) ; NPN model for BC547
.MODEL DIODE_1N5819 D(IS=1E-10 N=1.05 BV=50 RS=0.1) ; Model for diodes D1 and D2 (1N5819)

Simulation
.tran 0.1ms 10ms ; Transient simulation
.four 1k v(5) ; Fourier analysis at the rectified output (Node 5)

Control Block
.control
run
plot v(2) v(3) v(4) v(5) v(6) ; Voltages at key nodes
.endc

.end


What exactly would you consider to be expected behavior? Where did you get this schematic? What's actually driving the BJT base?

You should never AC couple to a lower R than the collector .   Let R1=R3 for matching signal peak and let R2>>= R1  e.g R1=2k, but you still have 0.65V Vbe offsetting the input and no H bias for AC+DC  So negative signals will not pass thru

If you add net labels to schematic then the plots will show these.

See this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/733601/bc547-transistor-rectifier-circuit-with-diodes-1n4007-and-capacitor

2 diode full wave rectification is usually associated with a center tapped transformer, as below:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

It isn't the most common use case to rectify the output of an amplifier, as you have tried to do. One reason is efficiency, or rather the inefficiency involved. One might rectify the output of an amplifier as part of some signal processing chain, but not for power.
If one did want to rectify the output of an amplifier, coupling the amplifier to the diodes via capacitors, as you have done, poses a problem. Since the diodes mostly prevent current from flowing in the reverse direction, placing a capacitor in series with a diode will cause the capacitor to charge, but then never discharge (or discharge only very slowly). Once charged, no further current will flow through the diode. So, your signal current would fall to near 0.
However, by adding resistors between the capacitors, and grounding their join point, it is possible to use capacitative coupling. An example is shown below. Note that the resistors and capacitors need to be sufficiently large for a given AC frequency to get a reasonable output. Note that the resistors will cause much of the energy in the signal to be wasted. However, at this point, I am assuming there is some other goal in mind, other than efficiency.

simulate this circuit

Next we will try using a phase splitter.

simulate this circuit

